# Table Boostrap mutiples llamadas a funcion

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo una tabla boostrap, configurada y funcional en cada fila he puesto un boton que ejecuta una función y cambio de color de boton.

Pero parece que la función es llamada varias veces,

Puse un consolole.Log y este se repite dos veces lo que me da a entender que la funcion es llamda dos veces, al usar la paginacion esto se acentúa subiendo uno conforme cambio de pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f3e99a6c02/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f3e99a6c02/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<h2>Manage Users</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Name </th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> RICHARD </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser1" userId = "1" userName="Richard">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> LEONARD </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser2" userId = "2" userName="Leonard">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 3 </td>
      <td> Cris </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser3" userId = "3" userName="Cris">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 4 </td>
      <td> Eva </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser4" userId = "4" userName="eva">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td> Paco </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser5" userId = "5" userName="Paco">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 6 </td>
      <td> Pedro </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser6" userId = "6" userName="Pedro">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> Susan </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser7" userId = "7" userName="Susan">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 8 </td>
      <td> April </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser8" userId = "8" userName="april">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> Rose </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser9" userId = "9" userName="Rose">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> Jenny </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser10" userId = "10" userName="jenny">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 //boostrap table init
    $(function () {
        $("#userTable").DataTable();
  
    });
 
 
 
//boostrap table configure
$("#userTable").DataTable({
  "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
 paginate: true
 //select: true,



});
 
 // redraw table page
$('#userTable').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    //alert( 'Table redrawn' );
 //if id (global) define, clear buttons class
 if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
     $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-primary");
  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-success");
  //and add to id button
  $("#"+id).addClass("btn-success");
 }

     $('.selectButton').click(function() {
   
   var este = this;
    myFunction(este);
    });
  
} );
 
//first page action button
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectButton').click(function() {
   var este = this;
   
    myFunction(este);
  });
});
 

//function for selectbuttons
function myFunction(este) {
 var userName = $(este).attr('userName');
 //create global var
 id = $(este).attr('id');

  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-success");
  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-primary");

 $(este).addClass("btn-success");
 
 console.log(id);
alert(userName);
}
 

  
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te diría como enfoque que pruebes a a hacer un juego de datos para instanciar Datatable en vez de hacerlo sobre el html, definiendo también un array de columnas donde se insertarán los rows según sus keys.

Habitualmente yo suelo escribir los eventos en el método "fnCreatedCell" debido a que he tenido si

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10710/fncreatedcell-with-jquery-document-ready-function

Comment: Esto es para boostrap?

Comment: Me dio la sensación de que el problema estaba en datatables js